How to scrap image from Magento script type="text/x-magento-init"
I'm using simple_html_dom.php function to scrap data to specific Magento site. I am able to scrap all of the things but can't able to find additional images which are comes from script type="text/x-magento-init" I tried all the way but can't able to fetch. Here are some sample code which I tried. Is it possible to scrap data from scrip tag which are available image in it?
> $scripts = $html->find('script',19);
>     forforeach ($scripts->find("<tag>") as $<tag>) 
>     {
>         foreach ($<tag>->find("img") as $img) //Start searching for img tag in all (divs) you found
>         {
>             echo $img->src . "<br>"; //Output the information from the img's src attribute (if the found tag is <img
> src="www.example.com/cat.png"> you will get www.example.com/cat.png as
> result)
>         }
>     }

Please find the attached
Thanks in advance

managed to get image urls ran script in laravel using simple_html_dom
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use simplehtmldom\HtmlDocument;

function scrapeImagesFromScriptTag($url) {
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    if (!$html) {
        die("Failed to load the HTML content.");
    }
    
    $dom = new HtmlDocument();
    $dom->load($html);

    $scriptTag = $dom->find('script[type="text/x-magento-init"]', 14); // Adjust index if needed

    if ($scriptTag) {
        $scriptContent = $scriptTag->innertext;

        if (empty($scriptContent)) {
            echo "Script content is empty for the found tag.<br>";
            return;
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        echo htmlspecialchars($scriptContent);
        echo "</pre>";

        $scriptContent = html_entity_decode($scriptContent);
        $data = json_decode($scriptContent, true);

        if ($data !== null) {
            if (isset($data['[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]']['mage/gallery/gallery']['data'])) {
                $images = $data['[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]']['mage/gallery/gallery']['data'];
                foreach ($images as $image) {
                    if (isset($image['img'])) {
                        echo "Image URL: " . $image['img'] . "<br>";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "Expected data structure not found in JSON.";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error decoding JSON: " . json_last_error_msg();
        }
    } else {
        echo "Script tag not found!";
    }

    $dom->clear();
    unset($dom);
}

ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');

$url = 'https://testurl.com/index.php/sku';  // Replace with actual URL
scrapeImagesFromScriptTag($url);
?>

and got this result
